Singular cardinals and $\kappa$-Lindelöf spaces
Say a space is $\kappa$-Lindelöf provided that for every open cover of the space, there exists a subcover of cardinality $<\kappa$. So $\aleph_0$-Lindelöf is compact, and $\aleph_1$-Lindelöf is Lindelöf.
For example, given a discrete space of infinite cardinality $\kappa$, the open cover of singletons has no subcover and is of size $\kappa$, showing the space is $\kappa^+$-Lindelöf.
Does there exist a singular cardinal $\kappa$ and a space which is $\kappa$-Lindelöf, but fails to be $\lambda$-Lindelöf for any cardinal $\lambda<\kappa$?

Yes, there is such a space. In fact I'll show that for any infinite limit cardinal $\kappa$, there is a space which is $\kappa$-Lindelöf but not $\lambda$-Lindelöf for any smaller $\lambda$. This includes all the infinite singular cardinals (assuming choice). So let $\kappa$ be an infinite limit cardinal.
For each cardinal $\lambda < \kappa$, let $X_\lambda$ be a set of size $\lambda$. Let $X = \bigsqcup_{\lambda < \kappa} X_\lambda$. Then $X$ has cardinality $\kappa$ (which is the best we could hope for). Define a topology on $X$ as follows: say that $A \subseteq X$ is closed if either $A = X$, or if the set of $\lambda < \kappa$ such that $A \cap X_\lambda \ne \emptyset$ is finite. So we have a topology which looks a bit like the cofinite topology if you zoom out and squint. Clearly this is indeed a topology.

This makes $X$ $\kappa$-Lindelöf. Indeed suppose $\mathcal U$ is an open cover of $X$. Let $U_0 \in \mathcal U$ be any nonempty element of the cover. Then $U_0$ fully contains all but finitely many of the $X_\lambda$. Since we can always choose a subfamily of $\mathcal U$ to cover $X_\lambda$ of cardinality at most $\lambda$, we can find a subcover of $\mathcal U$ of cardinality less than $\kappa$.
However, if $\lambda < \kappa$, consider the family $\mathcal U$ of all sets of the form $(X \setminus X_\lambda) \cup \{x\}$ where $x \in X_\lambda$. This is an open cover of $X$, but you always need all $\lambda$ of these sets to cover $X$. Hence $X$ is not $\lambda$-Lindelöf.

